# Parse nested map from a YAML document

Tags: go, parsing, yaml

I am having trouble with (what I believe to be) a simple issue.
I am trying to create a CLI using commando, and this CLI will read a configuration yaml, and then do stuff. However, I am stuck at the parsing of the config.yaml
The following is my code:

```
type Config struct {
    Apps map[string]App `yaml:"apps"`
    Branch string  `yaml:"branch"`
}
type App struct {
    hostName string `yaml:"hostName"`
}
.
. //func main, and other standard stuff goes here
.
commando.
        Register("read").
        AddArgument("config", "read yaml file", "./config.yaml").
        SetAction(
            func(args map[string]commando.ArgValue, flags map[string]commando.FlagValue) {
                    //args["config"] equates to ./config.yaml and I will give that below
                    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(args["config"].Value)
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }

                    var data2 Config
                    err3 := yaml.Unmarshal(file, &data2)
                    if err3 != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err3)
                    }
                    fmt.Printf("Ad demo?: %#v\n", data2.Apps["ad-demo"].hostName)
                    fmt.Printf("Data 2: %#v\n", data2)
            })
        commando.Parse(nil)
```

My config.yaml is as follows:

```
apps:
  ad-tag:
    hostName: ad-tag1.krg.io
  ad-demo:
    hostName: demo1.krg.io
branch: KAT-3821
```

This works **for the most part**. The problem is that the following prints:

```
Ad demo?: ""
Data 2: main.Config{Apps:map[string]main.App{"ad-demo":main.App{hostName:""}, "ad-tag":main.App{hostName:""}}, Branch:"KAT-3821"}
```

The hostName is coming up as an empty string.

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong? I feel like this should be very simple, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: export your `hostName` variable i.e. capitalize the variable inside the struct

Comment: Omg. I'm a dummy. I knew it was something small. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hostname should be exported, i.e. capitalized

```
type App struct {
    HostName string `yaml:"hostName"`
}
```

If you don't export it, packages such as `yaml` or `json` won't be able to read the field and populate it.

Comment: Thank you thank you! @Inian also had the same answer as a comment, but i'm not sure how to mark that as correct, pretty new to posting on SO